# add a page to a template/view

Tags: atk4

I want to add a page(page uses its own template) to a view that is called by another page.

this works and i get the data however i get 3copies of blog.php showing up on index.php I dont understand why this doing this.

index.php:

```
<?php
class page_index extends Page {
    function init(){
        parent::init();
        $p=$this;

        $p=$this->add('View',null,null,array('view/home'));
        $p->template->tryset('pageblog',$this->add('page_blog'));

    }
}
```

home.html (called by index.php):

```
<div>
<?$pageblog?>
</div>
```

blog.php:

```
<?php
class page_blog extends Page {
    function init(){
        parent::init();
        $page=$this;

        //Get Articles
        $articles=$this->add('Model_News')->getRows();

        $page->add('H1')->set('Latest News');

        foreach($articles as $article){
            $content=$this->add('view',null,null,array('view/blog'));
            $content->template->set('title',$article['title']);
            $content->template->set('content',$article['content']);
        }

    }
}
```

blog.html (template for blog.php)

```
<div>
<h3><?$title?></h3>
<p><?$content?></p>
<hr>
</div>
```

Comment: you sure you mean to add "page" to "view" ? usually it's other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, you are missing some of the fundamentals in here.

1. You don't add pages. ApiFrontend does it for you.
2. You can define template for your existing page, without need to add a view like that using defaultTemplate()
3. When you add object into an object, you can place it into a spot. If you manually insert the object into a template, it's not a good thing.
4. You can use lister for displaying entries like that.

---

page/index.php

```
class page_index extends Page {
    function init(){
        parent::init();
        $this->add('MVCLister',null,'News','News')->setModel('News');

    }
    function defaultTemplate(){
        return array('page/home');  // separate pages from views to avoid mess in templates
    }
}
```

templates/default/page/home.html:

```
<div>
<h1>My Blog page</h1>
<p>Welcome to my blog</p>
<hr/>
 <?News?>
   <?rows?>
   <?row?>
   <div><h3><?$title?></h3>
   <?$content?>
   </div>
   <?/row?>
   <?/rows?>
 <?/News?>
</div>
```

Now I need to make comment on the MVCLister. It's similar to MVCGrid, but it does not have a template by default, so you need to specify. 3rd argument defines where you want News to be displayed on the page. Fourth argument is the template, which you usually specify as "array(...)". Without array - it takes a chunk out of it's parent template. So in this case we take content of  use it for the MVCLister and put content back into the same tag replacing what you have there right now.

MVCLister looks for  in it's template, repeats it enough times and puts result into . Any tags inside  will be automatically assigned to your model fields with exact name.

Saves you plenty of typing :)